# Use Rust link Intel-MKl

Tags: c

I'm trying to use Rust link Intel-MKL library. I've included the MKL path in build.rs. But when I cargo run the project, it will return an error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-L" ... "-lresolv" "-lc" "-lm"
  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "_cblas_sasum", referenced from:
                _third_input in libMKL-Rust.a(main.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the [Intel MKL developer libraries](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html), the easiest way I have found is to use [`intel-mkl-src`](https://github.com/rust-math/intel-mkl-src) with the [`dynamic`](https://github.com/rust-math/intel-mkl-src#link-type-static-or-dynamic) feature.

### Cargo.toml

```rust
[dependencies]
#blas = "0.22.0"
cblas = "0.4.0"
#lapack = "0.19.0"
lapacke = "0.5.0"
intel-mkl-src = { version = "0.8.1", features = ["mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp"]}
```

I recommend using the `cblas` and `lapacke` crates, they are generally simpler to use, but if you prefer the FORTRAN APIs and manually handling the `work`spaces then use `blas` and `lapack`.

### main.rs

```rust
extern crate cblas;
extern crate lapacke;
extern crate intel_mkl_src;

use std::mem::take;
use lapacke::Layout;

fn main() {
    println!("BLAS example: daxpy ( y = alpha * x + y )");
    // https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/da4/group__double__blas__level1_ga8f99d6a644d3396aa32db472e0cfc91c.html
    let x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    let mut y = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
    let alpha = 2.0;
    let n = x.len();
    // y = 2 * [1, 2, 3, 4] + [1, 1, 1, 1] = [3, 5, 7, 9]
    unsafe { cblas::daxpy(n as i32, alpha, &x, 1, &mut y, 1); }

    println!("y = {:?}", y);

    println!("DGELS example: dgels (solve A * X = B)");
    // See dgels example here: https://netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html
    /*
            ( 1  1  1 )
            ( 2  3  4 )
        A = ( 3  5  2 )
            ( 4  2  5 )
            ( 5  4  3 )

            ( -10 -3 )
            (  12 14 )
        B = (  14 12 )
            (  16 16 )
            (  18 16 )

            ( 2 1 )
        X = ( 1 1 )
            ( 1 2 )

     */
    let mut a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0];
    let mut b = [-10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, -3.0, 14.0, 12.0, 16.0, 16.0];
    let m = 5;
    let n = 3;
    let nrhs = 2;
    let lda = 5;
    let ldb = 5;
    let mut info = 0;

    unsafe { info = lapacke::dgels(Layout::ColumnMajor, 'N' as u8, m, n, nrhs, &mut a, lda, &mut b, ldb) };
    println!("Info {}", info);
    // Note that the solution is written back into b
    println!("b = {:?}", b);
    // b is 5x2, but the solution x is 3x2, so we cut off extra data (remnants from b)
    let x: Vec<_> = b.chunks(5)
        .map(|c| c.chunks(3)
            .take(1)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()[0])
        .collect();
    // x is in column major form: [[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
    println!("x = {:?}", x);
}
```

I hope Intel release a Rust version of MKL, to avoid using the `unsafe` call!